# Calculating changes in three stock market indexes

Tags: java

In the following code example, the main issue begins with `// begin code duplication` and end with `// end code duplication`. As you can see, I need to process the `String[]` exactly the same way, then put the processed string into `indexMap`. The problem is that the name of each map keys are different. How do I generalize these almost exactly the same string operations?

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // run the main function
        Map<String, String> indexMap = getIndexMap();

        // display the desired result
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : indexMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getIndexMap() throws Exception {

        // src String[]
        String[] indexStringArr = new String[] {
                "NDX.US,15781.72,15766.22,15766.22,15766.22,15766.22",
                "DJIA.US,36398.21,36488.63,36421.14,36571.55,36396.19",
                "SPX.US,4786.35,4793.06,4788.64,4804.06,4778.08"
        };

        Map<String, String> indexMap = new HashMap<>();

        // begin code duplication
        String[] nasdaqArr = indexStringArr[0].split(",");
        List<String> nasdaq = Arrays.asList(nasdaqArr);

        String[] djiaArr = indexStringArr[1].split(",");
        List<String> djia = Arrays.asList(djiaArr);

        String[] sp500Arr = indexStringArr[2].split(",");
        List<String> sp500 = Arrays.asList(sp500Arr);

        // NASDAQ
        String nasPreviousPrice = nasdaq.get(1);
        String nasIndex = nasdaq.get(2);
        double nasChange = Double.parseDouble(nasIndex) - Double.parseDouble(nasPreviousPrice);
        double nasChangeRounded = round(nasChange, 2);
        double nasPercentChange = (nasChange / Double.parseDouble(nasPreviousPrice)) * 100;
        double nasPercentChangeRounded = round(nasPercentChange, 2);
        indexMap.put("NasIndex", nasIndex);
        indexMap.put("NasChange", String.valueOf(nasChangeRounded));
        indexMap.put("NasPercentChange", String.valueOf(nasPercentChangeRounded));

        // DJIA
        String djiaPreviousPrice = djia.get(1);
        String djiaIndex = djia.get(2);
        double djiaChange = Double.parseDouble(djiaIndex) - Double.parseDouble(djiaPreviousPrice);
        double djiaChangeRounded = round(djiaChange, 2);
        double djiaPercentChange = (djiaChange / Double.parseDouble(djiaPreviousPrice)) * 100;
        double djiaPercentChangeRounded = round(djiaPercentChange, 2);
        indexMap.put("djiaIndex", djiaIndex);
        indexMap.put("djiaChange", String.valueOf(djiaChangeRounded));
        indexMap.put("djiaPercentChange", String.valueOf(djiaPercentChangeRounded));

        // S&P 500
        String sp500PreviousPrice = sp500.get(1);
        String sp500Index = sp500.get(2);
        double sp500Change = Double.parseDouble(sp500Index) - Double.parseDouble(sp500PreviousPrice);
        double sp500ChangeRounded = round(sp500Change, 2);
        double sp500PercentChange = (sp500Change / Double.parseDouble(sp500PreviousPrice)) * 100;
        double sp500PercentChangeRounded = round(sp500PercentChange, 2);
        indexMap.put("Sp500Index", sp500Index);
        indexMap.put("Sp500Change", String.valueOf(sp500ChangeRounded));
        indexMap.put("Sp500PercentChange", String.valueOf(sp500PercentChangeRounded));
        // end code duplication

        return indexMap;
    }

    // helper function
    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **[LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)** Instead of **`HashMap`** to get data in ordered collection. **`HashMap`** is collection of Key and Value pair but **`HashMap`** does not give guaranty that insertion order will preserve.

**Change**

```
Map<String, String> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
```

**To**

```
Map<String, String> indexMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Here down i give simple example of **HashMap** with result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("Jack", "1917");
    user.put("John", "1791");
    user.put("Daniel", "1902");
    user.put("Michael", "1997");  
       
    for(Map.Entry m : user.entrySet()){    
       System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());    
    }  
}
```

**Output**

```
Michael 1997
John 1791
Daniel 1902
Jack 1917
```

Here down i will give example of **LinkedHashSet**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String,String> user = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    user.put("Jack", "1917");
    user.put("John", "1791");
    user.put("Daniel", "1902");
    user.put("Michael", "1997");  
       
    for(Map.Entry m : user.entrySet()){    
       System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());    
    }  
}
```

**Output**

```
Jack 1917
John 1791
Daniel 1902
Michael 1997
```

Answer (score 0):

I generalized it by creating a method for it:

```
    public static Map<String, String> processIndexToMap(String[] indexStringArr, int indexStringArrIndex, String indexName, Map<String, String> indexMap) throws Exception {
        String[] indexArr = indexStringArr[indexStringArrIndex].split(",");
        List<String> indexNameLst = Arrays.asList(indexArr);

        String indexPreviousPrice = indexNameLst.get(1);
        String indexNameIndex = indexNameLst.get(2);

        double indexChange = Double.parseDouble(indexNameIndex) - Double.parseDouble(indexPreviousPrice);
        double indexChangeRounded = round(indexChange, 2);
        double indexPercentChange = (indexChange / Double.parseDouble(indexPreviousPrice)) * 100;
        double indexPercentChangeRounded = round(indexPercentChange, 2);

        indexMap.put(indexName + "Index", indexNameIndex);
        indexMap.put(indexName + "Change", String.valueOf(indexChangeRounded));
        indexMap.put(indexName + "PercentChange", String.valueOf(indexPercentChangeRounded));
        return indexMap;
    }
```

And then calling it for the three different stocks:

```
    public static Map<String, String> getIndexMap(String[] indexStringArr) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
        processIndexToMap(indexStringArr, 0, "Nas", indexMap);
        processIndexToMap(indexStringArr, 1, "djia", indexMap);
        processIndexToMap(indexStringArr, 2, "Sp500", indexMap);
        return indexMap;
    }
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: I suggest you delete this answer and create a follow up question with a link back to this question so that you can get the new code reviewed.